# What should happen to Badge count when app is updated?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am testing one of the iOS apps which has Push Notification functionality. Suppose while testing I have sent some Push Notifications to the app so that app icon started showing badge icon on it. Now instead of viewing notification I updated the app to newer version. So what should happen in this case in ideal scenario? Should badge icons retained or removed?

Is there any document by apple where we can verify above scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Currently I also test a app with notifications and after upgrading the app, the badge count is still present. The app control the badge.

> An application is responsible for managing the badge number. If the application does not clear the badge, the push message(s) will remain in the notification center. After an application receives a push notification, it should remove the icon badge by setting the applicationIconBadgeNumber property of the UIApplication object to 0.

Source: http://docs.urbanairship.com/connect/ios_push.html#badge-and-autobadge

Apple Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

Comment: This feels like the intended behavior, you do not want to lose unread notifications during a application update. @subzero I would file defect :)

Comment: So does it mean the count should NOT be removed unless and until the Notifications are read, no matter if you upgrade the app? I do not know the correct behavior, I just came across one defect filed by the client which says that the count should be removed if the app is upgraded so I needed some doc regarding it which should specify correct behavior.

Comment: I think it is possible to remove the badge count by upgrading. The app is responsible for the badge count, so maybe the developers can set is to 0 while upgrading or after that.

Comment: Agree with that, but what I am not able to understand is 'what is ideal result for this?' to show a badge icon or Not to show. Considering Usability and continuity app should show a badge icon even after upgrading the app as user has not viewed the notification earlier but is it the expected or ideal flow?

Comment: My opinion is, yes, it is. But I think the stakeholders/product owners/business analysts/client of the app should take the decision.

Comment: What the behavior of an application should be is more an UX question and a bit offtopic on SQA, try asking on: http://ux.stackexchange.com/